# Beginner trying to ask the input and calculate the future value

Tags: python

```
Investment=float(input("How much do you want to invest?"))
Rate =float(input("what yield are you receiving?"))
Periods = int(input("how many periods is your investment?"))
periods_invest=(Rate/100**Periods)
Return_invest = (Investment)*(1 + Rate/100)*(periods_invest)
print(f"You receive ${Return_invest:.2f}")
```

Context is that I am not getting the proper rate of return.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Is [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Calculation) what you want to calculate? You need to use the correct operators and pay attention to operator precedence: In Python, [`**`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.pow) is the operator for exponentiation. It has a higher [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than multiplication which is the `*` operator. This means `a * b ** c` is `a * (b ** c)` and not `(a * b) ** c`.

```
investment = float(input("How much do you want to invest? "))
rate = float(input("What yield are you receiving? "))
periods = int(input("How many periods is your investment? "))
return_invest = investment * (1 + rate / 100) ** periods
print(f"You receive ${return_invest:.2f}")
```

Here is an exemplary run of that code:

```
How much do you want to invest? 1000
What yield are you receiving? 5
How many periods is your investment? 50
You receive $11467.40
```

Also, I have used variable names following the [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) naming convention. For more information, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).